# MSDeploy 3 and dbDacFx not recognizing parameters it claims it supports. Am I missing something?

Tags: msdeploy

Here is my commandline:

```
msdeploy.exe -verb:sync  -Source:dbDacFx="C:\MyDB.dacpac" -dest:dbDacFx="Data Source=myserver;Database=MyDB;userid=myuser;password=secret",wmsvc="https://www.myserver.com",username=myotheruser,password=anothersecret,BlockOnPossibleDataLoss="False" -verbose
```

The presence of that BlockOnPossibleDataLoss parameter causes this error:

```
Error Code: 109
More Information:
Error: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
Error: Provider 'dbDacFx' does not support setting 'BlockOnPossibleDataLoss'.
Error count: 1.
```

If I take it out the BlockOnPossibleDataLoss parameter, it *works fine*.

If I put in a garbage setting like this:

```
msdeploy.exe -verb:sync  -Source:dbDacFx="C:\MyDB.dacpac" -dest:dbDacFx="Data Source=myserver;Database=MyDB;userid=myuser;password=secret",wmsvc="https://www.myserver.com",username=myotheruser,password=anothersecret,asdfghjkl="False" -verbose
```

I get this error message:

```
Error: The provider 'dbDacFx' does not support the 'asdfghjkl' setting. Supporte
d settings are (dropDestinationDatabase, dacpacAction, includeData, commandTimeo
ut, AllowDropBlockingAssemblies, AllowIncompatiblePlatform, BackupDatabaseBefore
Changes, BlockOnPossibleDataLoss, BlockWhenDriftDetected, CommentOutSetVarDeclar
ations, CompareUsingTargetCollation, CreateNewDatabase, DeployDatabaseInSingleUs
erMode, DisableAndReenableDdlTriggers, DoNotAlterChangeDataCaptureObjects, DoNot
AlterReplicatedObjects, DropConstraintsNotInSource, DropDmlTriggersNotInSource,
DropExtendedPropertiesNotInSource, DropIndexesNotInSource, DropObjectsNotInSourc
e, DropPermissionsNotInSource, DropRoleMembersNotInSource, GenerateSmartDefaults
, IgnoreAnsiNulls, IgnoreAuthorizer, IgnoreColumnCollation, IgnoreComments, Igno
reCryptographicProviderFilePath, IgnoreDdlTriggerOrder, IgnoreDdlTriggerState, I
gnoreDefaultSchema, IgnoreDmlTriggerOrder, IgnoreDmlTriggerState, IgnoreExtended
Properties, IgnoreFileAndLogFilePath, IgnoreFilegroupPlacement, IgnoreFileSize,
IgnoreFillFactor, IgnoreFullTextCatalogFilePath, IgnoreIdentitySeed, IgnoreIncre
ment, IgnoreIndexOptions, IgnoreIndexPadding, IgnoreKeywordCasing, IgnoreLockHin
tsOnIndexes, IgnoreLoginSids, IgnoreNotForReplication, IgnoreObjectPlacementOnPa
rtitionScheme, IgnorePartitionSchemes, IgnorePermissions, IgnoreQuotedIdentifier
s, IgnoreRoleMembership, IgnoreRouteLifetime, IgnoreSemicolonBetweenStatements,
IgnoreTableOptions, IgnoreUserSettingsObjects, IgnoreWhitespace, IgnoreWithNoche
ckOnCheckConstraints, IgnoreWithNocheckOnForeignKeys, IncludeCompositeObjects, I
ncludeTransactionalScripts, NoAlterStatementsToChangeClrTypes, PopulateFilesOnFi
leGroups, RegisterDataTierApplication, RunDeploymentPlanExecutors, ScriptDatabas
eCollation, ScriptDatabaseCompatibility, ScriptDatabaseOptions, ScriptDeployStat
eChecks, ScriptFileSize, ScriptNewConstraintValidation, ScriptRefreshModule, Tre
atVerificationErrorsAsWarnings, UnmodifiableObjectWarnings, VerifyCollationCompa
tibility, VerifyDeployment, authType, computerName, encryptPassword, includeAcls
, password, prefetchPayload, userName, wmsvc).
Error count: 1.
```

Note that it *includes* BlockOnPossibleDataLoss as one of the supported settings in the error message about not supporting some other garbage parameter. This is totally contradictory. Further, if you simply ask the dbDacFx provider what it supports:

```
msdeploy.exe -Help -Source:dbDacFx
```

It lists a host of settings, including:

```
Provider Setting:  BlockOnPossibleDataLoss

   A true or false value for the 'BlockOnPossibleDataLoss'
   setting.
```

I understand from reading about dbDacFx and many other users frustrated at its incompleteness that it has been "undercooked". But this is the first time I've realized how absurd the situation is where it reports that it doesn't support a specific parameter, yet lists it among the parameters it supports.

Will this be fixed, or should I discard dbDacFx? Am I missing something?